# cognito: can i generate the same identityID as facebook?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

im trying to access to my dataset IdentityID.
My problem: when i login with facebook or twitter they assign the same IdentityID but when i login with my email and password it's not the same identityID so i can't get the dataset of my last login.